# Customized Scroll Bar doesn't appear on Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, scrollbar

I just created a customized scroll bar in CSS, in Google Chrome the scroll bar displays well and with the style I created for it, but in Internet explorer doesn't seem to be appearing at all... It's appearing the default scroll bar. How can I make this scroll bar appear on IE as well?

Here's a Jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/5Wne5/

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width:6px;
    border-radius:10px;
} 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background-color:#B03C3F;
    border-radius:10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
    background-color:#BF4649;
    border:1px solid #333333;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active{
    background-color:#A6393D;
    border:1px solid #333333;
} 
::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    border:1px gray solid;
    border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 6px #1f1f1f;
}
```

Comment: Your code says it all. `-webkit-` is only for Webkit browsers: Chrome, Safari, Opera 15+ are all Webkit. They may or may not support that code. Internet Explorer is not a Webkit browser. That's why it will not work. You can Google for IE-specific code that will do it for IE, but I believe you'll be out of luck when it comes to Firefox, I don't think they have this ability. Changing the style of an Operating System function is not recommended, that's why it's not part of W3C specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-webkit-` is only supported by Safari, Chrome, Opera 15+ as mentioned in the comments.

Therefore, your `CSS` will not work in IE but you could use this:

```
scrollbar-base-color: #C0C0C0;
scrollbar-base-color: #C0C0C0;
scrollbar-3dlight-color: #C0C0C0;
scrollbar-highlight-color: #C0C0C0;
scrollbar-track-color: #EBEBEB;
scrollbar-arrow-color: black;
scrollbar-shadow-color: #C0C0C0;
scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: #C0C0C0;
```

[image: http://dottorocdn.com/images/help/page_spec/scrollbar.gif]

Credits for the above code: http://codemug.com/html/custom-scrollbars-using-css/

Above code doesn't work on all browsers so to avoid that you could use jQuery.

There are several JS-Plugins to achieve the same look and feel for IE like in Webkit.

- [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller)
- [nanoScrollerJS](http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/)

Comment: Erm, this is wrong. There IS an equivalent for IE, in fact IE was the pioneer, because back in the old days we could change the scrollbar colours for IE ... 5? etc.

Comment: Only problem with that is the compatibility issue :) That is why I recommended Jquery plugins but I posted the alternative for you :)

Comment: Saw your update. We've misunderstood each other. When you say `There's no IE equivalent to ::-webkit-scrollbar and friends but you could use this:`, that code **is** an IE equivalent. That's what I was saying. I'm not saying jQuery plugins aren't a better option because of compatibility, only that an equivalent for IE does in fact exist.

Comment: I see your point, I will edit that part :) Sorry to mislead you there

Comment: Great. I think you should do away with the IE-only code, just cite that scrollbar customisability using CSS is vendor-specific, has patchy support, and doesn't look that great. Then move on to your proposition of using Javascript to replace the scrollbars entirely, as it's more customisable and has more wide-range browser support. That would make your answer better.

Answer (score 1):

Your code says it all. `-webkit-` is only for Webkit browsers: Chrome, Safari, Opera 15+ are all Webkit. They may or may not support that code.

Internet Explorer is not a Webkit browser. That's why it will not work.

Firefox does not support scrollbar changing anymore.

Changing the style of an Operating System function is not recommended, that's why it's not part of W3C specification.

Code for IE:

```
scrollbar-base-color: #C0C0C0;
scrollbar-base-color: #C0C0C0;
scrollbar-3dlight-color: #C0C0C0;
scrollbar-highlight-color: #C0C0C0;
scrollbar-track-color: #EBEBEB;
scrollbar-arrow-color: black;
scrollbar-shadow-color: #C0C0C0;
scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: #C0C0C0;
```

Info: http://codemug.com/html/custom-scrollbars-using-css/

Good image (from above source) explaining what each property does:

[image: Image explaining what each of the IE properties do to affect the scrollbar]